# ORACLE update two CLOB columns - possible table lock for further updates?

Tags: php, oracle, clob

I need to update an ORA table with two CLOB columns.

I have found many solutions for this (one with `select x, y into x_loc, y_loc from table for update` and then do a `dbms_lob.write()` + `commit`) but I realized that this one is as simple as it should be:

```
UPDATE table SET
    clob1 = TO_CLOB(VARCHAR2_VALUE),
    clob2 = TO_CLOB(VARCHAR2_VALUE)
WHERE condition
```

After executing this query from PHP application I encounter strange behavior when I cannot execute any other update on that table (and/or concrete row) - the application just hangs on right on another update (confirmed by debugging). When trying to do update query using `sqldeveloper` it seems there is no lock issue.

Is there any possibility that the table/row remained locked after the CLOB update?
Should I did/do a commit after the CLOB update using the given update query?
How can I release this lock if it is there?

Many thanks for Your answers!

Comment: @iddqd Please, enclose it in a full sentence and post it as answer so I can accept Your answer. Of course, after doing a COMMIT alone a table is released ;-) Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must commit every DML query (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) .

It does not matter whether you use CLOB or no.

Comment: Not sure about "must commit after each INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE" - didn't do so til now and no problem occured until updating CLOB. But commiting after CLOB update worked (released lock) and is working (no locks since then). Thanks!